# Input 0 of layer "bidirectional" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. shape received: (None, 32)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Here is the snippet of code:

```
vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=MAX_FEATURES,
                               output_sequence_length=1800,
                               output_mode='int')
vectorizer.adapt(X.values)
vectorized_text = vectorizer(X.values)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((vectorized_text, y))
dataset = dataset.cache()
dataset = dataset.shuffle(160000)
dataset = dataset.batch(16)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(8)

train = dataset.take(int(len(dataset)*.7))
val = dataset.skip(int(len(dataset)*.7)).take(int(len(dataset)*.2))
test = dataset.skip(int(len(dataset)*.9)).take(int(len(dataset)*.1))

model = Sequential()
# Create the embedding layer 
model.add(Embedding(MAX_FEATURES+1, 32))
# Bidirectional LSTM Layer
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, activation='tanh')))
# Feature extractor Fully connected layers
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
# Final layer 
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='BinaryCrossentropy', optimizer='Adam')
model.summary()

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding (Embedding)       (None, None, 32)          6400032   
                                                                 
 bidirectional (Bidirectiona  (None, 64)               16640     
 l)                                                              
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 128)               8320      
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 256)               33024     
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 128)               32896     
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 6)                 774       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 6,491,686
Trainable params: 6,491,686
Non-trainable params: 0

history = model.fit(train, epochs=1, validation_data=val)
input_text = vectorizer('You freaking suck! I am going to hit you.')
```

It is giving me the error:

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

```
Input 0 of layer "bidirectional" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 32)

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int64)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```

I understand that it is expecting a 3dim input and is receiving a 2dim input. However I am not sure how to fix this. Ive tried:

train = train.map(lambda x, y: (tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1), y))

I've tried taking out the Bidirectional as well with the same error appearing.

Comment: By taking out Bidirectional, you mean just using an LSTM with the same parameters as inside the Bidirectional?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of design. It's not possible to have a final layer of 6 output when you use [`BinaryCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy).

If `y` looks like `[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]`, you have to use [`CategoricalCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy) but if `y` is something like `[2, 5, 3, 1]`, you should use [`SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy):

```
# y = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ...]
model.compile(loss='CategoricalCrossentropy', optimizer='Adam')

# OR

# y = [2, 5, 3, 1, ...]
model.compile(loss='SparseCategoricalCrossentropy', optimizer='Adam')
```

Furthermore, you have to pass an array to `vectorizer` even if you want to classify only one sentence:

```
#                HERE --v                                         --v
input_text = vectorizer(['You freaking suck! I am going to hit you.'])
```

Test:

```
>>> model.predict(input_text)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 472ms/step
array([[0.50885   , 0.50899976, 0.508887  , 0.49025747, 0.5067212 ,
        0.48000643]], dtype=float32)
```